# Adding formula in if else formula in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi all this is one of my formula in my crystal report. How can i add in this condition if {ardoc.doctype}= "NS" then display the result from below condition

```
  if {xtcwt_ardoc.BillTo} = "" then
 "0"
 else if {xtcwt_ardoc.BillTo} = "DEFAULT" then
 "0"
 else
 {xtcwt_soaddress.FinancialName}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if {ardoc.billto}= "NS"
(
 if {xtcwt_ardoc.BillTo} = "" then
 "0"
 else if {xtcwt_ardoc.BillTo} = "DEFAULT" then
 "0"
 else
 {xtcwt_soaddress.FinancialName}
)
else
(
//your code
)
```